# Product is not displaying in listing in Magento after import?

Tags: magento, import, product

[image]
I have created csv file and import that using `System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow-Profile`

I found that in `Catalog -> Manage Categories` in `Category Products`, product is displaying
but in Manage Products product is not displaying.

and in database `catalog_product_flat_1` table has not entry for that product and in other tables there is entry for that product

I have Re-index data and cleared cache but no solution..

Please help some one..

Comment: Do you have any filters applied in Manage products? (or any custom extension that might alter the grid?). Try searching it by SKU or look in catalog_product_entity table (search by sku) and try editing the product directy (changing the edit url).

Comment: Yes. I have installed extensions. and entry is there in catalog_product_entity table

Comment: catalog_product_flat_1 has no entry... but do you have use flat table enabled?

Comment: From System -> Catalog -> Use Flat Catalog Product => yes

Comment: Someone else seems to have encountered the same issue: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/266001/ ... which Magento version are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checking the data in `catalog_product_entity_int` should display if there is any missing record.

The Manage Products Grid Collection query has the following inner joins:

```
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 0) 
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '102') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 0)
```

In your case it seems that there is no record for **product status** in `catalog_product_entity_int` causing the product not to be displayed in the grid, but to be displayed in **Category Products** (where product's status is not checked).

The source of the problem is related to the value 1 in status column (csv file used for import). DataFlow relies on text values for the attribute (Enabled/Disabled).

Comment: is the value for status still missing from `catalog_product_entity_int`?

Comment: Finally Done..changed all values for visibility and tax class, and reference from export existing products using data profile export

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`' at line 1

Comment: When i run the above query iam getiing following error message

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me because of a special character in the product name. In my case the word "Crème" was creating all the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have the field "status" in you CSV file is set to Enable or Disable.

It happened to me after I forgot to save my CSV file with all values enclosed in " ". The dataflow profiles import returned an error.  And even after I tried to feed the correct CSV later, all products have disappeared from product grid (but remained in Catalogs related product list)

The way I solved it - was to create a temporary product and fill as many fields as possible. Perform an dataflow profile export selecting "Export: All Fields"

When I got my new CSV file, I compared fields of my new product with the ones of the hidden ones.   The field "status" simply had no value. And it must be either Enabled or Disabled